# how to calculate amount add to cart?

Tags: swift3

I am trying to calculate the total of product price all the products. but the previous cell does not add up

[image]

code:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! AddChartTableViewCell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    let model = self.realm.objects(addCart.self)[indexPath.row]

    cell.chartBrand.text = model.name
    cell.chartPrice.text = model.productPrice

    let imageProctURL = model.chartImage
    cell.chartImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageProctURL!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "dummy"))

    stepper = KWStepper(decrementButton: cell.decrementButton, incrementButton: cell.incrementButton)


    stepper
        .maximumValue(100)
        .minimumValue(1)
        .stepValue(1)
        .valueChanged { [unowned self] stepper in
            var total = 0.0
            self.tempCount = stepper.value
            let prices  = (model.productPrice! as NSString).doubleValue
            let localTotal = prices * self.tempCount!
            total += (prices) * (self.tempCount)!
            print (" \(total)")

            self.subTotal.text = String(total)
    }

    return cell
}
```

How to get cell value which just goes off the screen?

Comment: You need to know how UITableViewCell behaves in UITableView. UITableView 're-uses' UITableViewCell. Also UITableView populates cell based on index. If you want to calculate some thing create a global variable and use UITableView Delegates to parse that cell property.

Comment: @SaqibOmer Better yet, **don't use `UITableViewCell`s to calculate data**. Use a data source for this.

Comment: It was requirement in question that he wanted to use tableview. Data source, is not doubt right way to do calculations. @the4kman